# Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone: Font Segoe WP does not compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, xna-4.0

I've just installed Windows 8 and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone... but I'm no longer able to compile my XNA projects that contain spritefonts of type Segoe WP (the same projects do compile successfully with Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone):

```
<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics">
    <Asset Type="Graphics:FontDescription">

    <!--
    Modify this string to change the font that will be imported.
    -->
    <FontName>Segoe WP</FontName>

    <!--
    Size is a float value, measured in points. Modify this value to change
    the size of the font.
    -->
    <Size>14</Size>

    ...
</XnaContent>
```

The code snippet here above always generates the following build error:

`Error  1   Building content threw NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Interop.KerningHelper.GetCharacterSpacing(Char c)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.FontDescriptionProcessor.Process(FontDescription input, ContentProcessorContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentProcessor'2.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentProcessor.Process(Object input, ContentProcessorContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAssetWorker(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.RunTheBuild()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Tasks.BuildContent.RemoteProxy.RunTheBuild(BuildCoordinatorSettings settings, TimestampCache timestampCache, ITaskItem[] sourceAssets, String[]& outputContent, String[]& rebuiltContent, String[]& intermediates, Dictionary'2& dependencyTimestamps, KeyValuePair'2[]& warnings)`

If I replace `<FontName>Segoe WP</FontName>` with `<FontName>Segoe UI Mono</FontName>`, then the compilation succeeds.

Does anybody experienced something similar? Is there a workaround/fix? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from within the content processor. For some reason, that font isn't supported by the internal `GetCharacterSpacing` method that is used to figure out how wide the characters are.

(To wildly guess at the cause: maybe the 2012 build process is using a newer version of the .NET framework - eg: 4.5 vs 4.0 - and that particular method doesn't work the same between versions for some crazy reason. You could maybe mess about with MSBuild - but that's way too much effort.)

If it worked in 2010, you could simply directly use the resulting `xnb` file from a build done in that IDE.

**A better option might be to use [Nuclex.Fonts](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/wiki/NuclexFonts).** This uses FreeType to render the fonts - so it doesn't require that Windows API at all. It also gives better results than XNA's built-in processor (mostly because it doesn't lossy-compress its output). And it is a drop-in replacement - it reads the same XML files and outputs the same `SpriteFont` objects.

Comment: Is Nuclex.Fonts still supported/maintained? I've tried the binary distribution... but it does not work with Visual Studio 2012: Error loading pipeline assembly "H:\lib\WindowsPhone.Nuclex.Fonts.Content.TrueTypeImporter.dll. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah. Aside from checking you have the right path and everything, I don't know (same speculation from my answer applies). It's not something that I've actually tried. I suppose you could try building it from source. Or try the [content pipeline debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/11/01/xna-content-pipeline-debugging-4-0.aspx) (if *that* works!)

Comment: Just installed a few updates... and the project compiles again.